# Problemas al intentar cerrar un alert dialog

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en Xamarin Android, la cual usa un alert dialog para mostrar un proceso de carga, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es al momento de cerrar el alert dialog, pues este no se cierra y ya he probado de varias maneras, use el dismiss, cancel y hiden, pero de nunguna manera logro poder cerrar el alert dialog. 
:
Este es mi .cs:

```
private void ProgressBar(bool activate)
{
    int padding = 30;
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Horizontal;
    linearLayout.SetPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

    ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(this);
    progress.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
    layout.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
    TextView textView = new TextView(this)
    {
        Text = "Enviando..."
    };
    textView.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
    textView.TextSize = 20;

    linearLayout.AddView(progress);
    linearLayout.AddView(textView);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.SetCancelable(true);
    builder.SetView(linearLayout);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();

    if (activate)
    {
        dialog.Show();

        dialog.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
        Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
    }
    else
    {
        dialog.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
        Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);

        dialog.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero en caso que la variable `activate` tome valor `True` la sentencia `dialog.Dismiss();` no se ejecutará en ningún caso, si esa es la función que cierra el `AlertDialog`, pues está claro que no se cerrará.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando aca, es que estas cerrando otro dialogo diferente al que creaste.

Tu metodo hace basicamente esto:

```
private void ProgressBar(bool activate)
{
    //Seteo un dialogo
    //Creo un dialogo, sin importar si es para abrir o cerrar
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();

    if (activate)
    {
        //abro el dialogo
        dialog.Show();

        dialog.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
        Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
    }
    else
    {
        //Cierro el dialogo, pero no el que cree antes, si no el que cree en esta vuelta
        dialog.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
        Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);

        dialog.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

Asi que tu problema es que este metodo, que tiene que abrir y cerrar, abre y cierra cosas distintas.

Tenes que tener un metodo que si necesita lanzar el dialogo, lo cree, lo abra, y te quedes con una referencia a ese dialogo, para luego al cerrarlo, saber que dialogo cerrar.

Algo asi:

```
//Por algun lado, global a estos metodos
AlertDialog dialog = null;

private void ProgressBar(bool activate)
{

    if (activate)
    {
        //Creo un dialogo, sin importar si es para abrir o cerrar
        dialog = CrearElDialogo();
        dialog.Show();
        dialog.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
        Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
    }
    else
    {
        //Cierro el dialogo, 
        dialog.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
        Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
        dialog.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu excelente respusta no me habia dado cuanta de eso, me fue muy util